# Index was outside the bounds of the array. C#

Tags: c#

i have a code for Genetic algorithm's Roullete Wheel. my program shows error when my iteration is more than 1000 iterations but it works very good when the iteration less than 1000. 
here is my code

```
private double[] roulleteWheel(double[] nilaiFitnessRil)
    {
        double[] resultRW = new double[nilaiFitnessRil.GetLength(0)];
        double[] probKromosom = new double[nilaiFitnessRil.GetLength(0)];
        double[] probKumulatif = new double[nilaiFitnessRil.GetLength(0)];
        double pilih=0;
        Random random = new Random();
        double rnd;
        double total = 0;
        double temp = 0;
        //count total fitness
        for (int i = 0; i < nilaiFitnessRil.Length; i++)
        {
            total += nilaiFitnessRil[i];

        }
        listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("total fitness adalah {0}",total));
        //count probability for each chromosome
        listBox1.Items.Add("result of probabilty for each chromosome");
        for (int i = 0; i < nilaiFitnessRil.Length; i++)
        {
            probKromosom[i] = Math.Round(nilaiFitnessRil[i] / total, 4);
            listBox1.Items.Add(probKromosom[i].ToString());
        }
        //count cumulative probability
        listBox1.Items.Add("result of cumulative probabilty ");
        for (int i = 0; i < probKromosom.Length; i++)
        {
            temp += probKromosom[i];
            probKumulatif[i] = temp;
            listBox1.Items.Add(probKumulatif[i].ToString());
        }
        //selecting a chromosome by its cumulative probability with a random value

        listBox1.Items.Add(" roullete wheel");
        for (int n = 0; n < resultRil.Length; n++)
        {
            rnd = random.NextDouble() * 1.0 - 0.0;
            //listBox1.Items.Add(rnd.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < probKumulatif.Length; i++)
            {
           //this is where the Index was outside the bounds of the array appear 
                if (probKumulatif[i] <= rnd && probKumulatif[i + 1] > rnd ) 
                {
                    pilih = resultRil[i + 1];
                }
                else if ( rnd <= probKumulatif[0])
                {
                    pilih = resultRil[0];
                }


            }
            resultRil[n] = pilih;
            resultRW[n] = resultRil[n];
        }
        PrintArray(resultRW, listBox1);
            return resultRW;
    }
```

this is where the program was terminated cause by Index was outside the bounds of the array

```
 if (probKumulatif[i] <= rnd && probKumulatif[i + 1] > rnd ) 
                {
                    pilih = resultRil[i + 1];
                }
                else if ( rnd <= probKumulatif[0])
                {
                    pilih = resultRil[0];
                }
```

Comment: Any question hidden in your posting?

Comment: the program always terminated when the iteration is more than 1000 but when its less than 1000 it works very good. iteration what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an index out of bounds because you're referring to `i + 1` within the loop when you are looping through every item. Therefore one the last iteration you will attempt to access `probKumulatif[probKumulatif.Length]` which doesn't exist. Try looping through to `probKumulatif.Length - 1`

```
// *** On this line ***
for (int i = 0; i < probKumulatif.Length - 1; i++)
{
    //this is where the Index was outside the bounds of the array appear 
    if (probKumulatif[i] <= rnd && probKumulatif[i + 1] > rnd ) 
    {
        pilih = resultRil[i + 1];
    }
    else if ( rnd <= probKumulatif[0])
    {
        pilih = resultRil[0];
    }
}
```

You're also referring to `resultRil` using `i` and not `n`. If you mean `n` then the same can be applied as above as you access `resultRil[i + 1]`

```
for (int n = 0; n < resultRil.Length - 1; n++)
{
    ...
}
```

You may need to refer to `resultRil` using `n` in the inner loop

```
pilih = resultRil[n + 1];
```

Comment: it works. thank you very much Daniel. im referring resultRil because i want to choose the resultRil by selecting by ProbKumulatif with a rnd. but i think i should put probkumulatif and resultRil in a struct so i can select both in 1 looping. what do you think?

Comment: If they are part of the same object then it would be good to put them into a class together.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < probKumulatif.Length; i++)
{
    //this is where the Index was outside the bounds of the array appear 
    if (probKumulatif[i] <= rnd && probKumulatif[i + 1] > rnd )
```

What happens on the last iteration of this loop, when `i == probKumulatif.Length - 1`?

If `probKumulatif[i] <= rnd` is true, then `probKumulatif[i + 1] > rnd` will be evaluated, and since `i == probKumulatif.Length - 1`, then `i + 1 == probKumulatif.Length` - so you try to access `probKumulatif[probKumulatif.Length]`, which causes your exception!

Note that since `rnd` is *random*, this will only happen sometimes, with greater probability the more times you run it!

Comment: yeah when i == probKumulatif.Length - 1 it works. thank you very much Blorgbeard.

Answer (score 0):

simple. because at the last run of the loop probKumulatif[i + 1]  tries to reach the probKumulatif[probKumulatif.Length] which is not allowed. the max index you can reach is probKumulatif[probKumulatif.Length-1]. please try to debug your code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you tried to access array at the index that out of its range.
You can simply check as following:

```
if (probKumulatif[i] <= rnd && (probKumulatif.Length >= i+1 && probKumulatif[i + 1] > rnd) ) 
{
    pilih = resultRil[i + 1];
 }
else if ( rnd <= probKumulatif[0])
{
    pilih = resultRil[0];
}
```

but I would suggest for chage the for loop insteads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < probKumulatif.Length-1; i++)
{
//Keep it the same.
}
```